# List the rows containing only the latest datetime in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a table which contains 4 columns out of which one is datetime. I want to get the output of only the rows that have the latest datetime. How can I achieve this?

Comment: some sample data and desired output will be appreciated

Comment: Show us your current code attempt. And add some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: BTW, which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum or a code-writing service, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a specific programming question that can be answered rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [edit] your question to conform with the site rules. Overly broad or off-topic questions such as this one are often closed, but if edited to ask an answerable question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only 1 record form your entire table without any grouping, in that case you can try like following.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Your_Table]
ORDER BY DATE_COLUMN DESC
```

If you want to select 1 record for each group, you can try like following.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Group_By_Column_Name] 
                         ORDER BY DATE_COLUMN DESC) AS RN
)T
 WHERE RN =1
```

Comment: Will this include ties? "only the _rows_ that have the latest datetime"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4(DateTime COL) FROM Table
WHERE COL4 = (SELECT MAX(COL4) FROM TABLE)
```

MAX IN Different Group

```
 WITH CTE AS 
 (
   SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4(DateTime COL), 
             DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY COl_name_For_GROUP 
                             ORDER BY COL4(DateTime COL) DESC) AS RANK 
   FROM Table_name
 )
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4(DateTime COL) FROM CTE
    WHERE RANK =1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows having the maximum date value. Give a rank using ***`DENSE_RANK`*** function order by descending order of date.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = dense_rank() over(
       order by [date_col] desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select [col1], [col2], [col3], [date_col] from cte
where [rn] = 1;
```